# Why does it return "undefined" instead of the result from the function, i.e one of the console log expressions based on my arguments?

Tags: javascript, function, console, return, conditional-statements

Based on the arguments passed in (10, 20), I would expect it would return "Omg" when invoked. Why do I get "undefined"?

```
function ifko (a, b) {
 const lol = 20;
 const result = lol > a + b ? console.log("Super!") : console.log("Omg");
 return result;
 
}

console.log(ifko(10, 20));
```

Comment: Because `console.log()` returns `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks. Any alternatives I could use instead of console.log to get one of these strings returned?

Comment: @MilošLeng `lol > a + b ? "Super!" : "Omg";` - just don't `console.log` them

Comment: thanks. I just solved it by using template literal.